# MySQL creating a table inside a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code that i am trying to create a table within a database using mySQL incorporated in php code. I will show my code below. I cant seem to get it to work as even when i have MySQL activated on my XAMPP panel and therefore, clearly have connection, an error is produced with creating the table

```
<?php
$link = @mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root'); /* Open link to mysql database (making an attempt to make a connection to MySQL server */
if ($link) {  // If this succeeds, do the following lines
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName
(
        muqID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        dateTIME DATETIME,
        taskTime FLOAT(4,2),
        useTime VARCHAR(60),
        usedM VARCHAR(40),
        freqRate VARCHAR(200),
        gender CHAR(1),
        age TINYINT UNSIGNED,
        email VARCHAR(100),
        comment VARCHAR(3000)
)";
    $result = mysqli_query ( $link, $sql );
    echo ($result ? 'table sql created successfully' : 'Error creating table') . ": $sql"; // If result is true then echo success, if false, echo fail. 
    mysqli_close($link); /* Close link to mysql database */
} else {  // Otherwise, if doesnt succeed then echo 
    echo 'Nothing happened';
}
```

Comment: Are you able to catch the error being thrown in your logs or use a try catch statement?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a safe default for all string-like fields unless you have a compelling reason to alter it. Email addresses are quite frequently ridiculously long and, by spec, can be up to ~250 characters. Using `VARCHAR(100)` for these is a problem.